# If else statement with clicked function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to enable a dark theme on a little project i have. so i want to have "OFF" green on default and "ON" red on default. but it doesn't work, all it does is running the else statement.

```js
function darkMode() {
 jQuery('#darkModeIcon').click(function(){
   $(this).data('clicked', true);
 });

 if(jQuery('#darkModeIcon').data('clicked')) {
  $('body').toggleClass('darkmode');
  $('#darkModeOn').toggleClass('darkModeTextBold');
  $('#darkModeOff').toggleClass('darkModeTextNormal');
 } 

 else {
  $('#darkModeOn').toggleClass('darkModeTextNormal');
  $('#darkModeOff').toggleClass('darkModeTextBold');
 } 
}
$(document).ready(darkMode);
```

```css
.darkModeTextNormal {
 font-weight: normal !important;
 color: red !important;
}

.darkModeTextBold {
 font-weight: bold !important;
 color: #2ecc71 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="darkmodetext" id="darkModeIcon">Darkmode <span id="darkModeOn">ON</span><span>/</span><span id="darkModeOff">OFF</span></p>
```

Comment: Where are you calling this function `darkMode`?

Comment: Could have just added an onclick on both spans. One to run the dark mode code and one to run the normal mode code.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan fixed, forgot to add in question.

Comment: Well, your `if/else` is only called once, at the point that the jQuery object `jQuery('#darkModeIcon')` has no data, so it goes to the `else`. Put the `if` within the function for the `click` handler.`